# Calculate largest tanker volume in one dimensional array

Tags: algorithm

I have the following puzzle:
Create a method to calculate the largest tanker volume that will be used to hold floodwater. Method input: a one-dimensional array of integers and one integer value that represents the width of the tanker.

```
integer getLargestTanker(Integer width, Integer[] values)
```

The one-dimensional array contains integer values that represent the tanker heights. The distance between those integer values in the array represents the tanker length.

### Example

Let's say we have the following array:
`{2, 9, 6, 3, 5, 7}`
We need to pick two numbers such that the product of the **effective** height and length (distance between those two numbers) is the maximum. If we pick 2 and 9, the effective tanker height is: 2 and the distance is 1. In this example, the maximum tanker volume value would be 7x4x(static given width). Because we should choose heights: 9 and 7. **Explanation**: the effective height is 7 (since it's a tanker that holds water). The length of the tanker is 4 (index-1 and index-7).

### My Solution

Two nested loops. Complexity is O(n^2). I strongly believe that there should be a better solution, but I couldn't come up with one. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Volume 74 or 28 in your example?

Comment: It's 28: I wrote 7 x 4 (with asterisk and stackoverflow formatted it to 74). thanks a lot for note

Comment: Common DSA question: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-rectangle-under-histogram/

Comment: Thanks Abhinav, But I think it's different. In my case, I don't consider the numbers between the two selected numbers. However, this can still be helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pairing two heights, the volume is determined by the minimum height.

Then, we focus here on the determination of the min height of this pair.
For each index `i`, corresponding to a height `A[i]`, we determine the minimum and the maximum indices corresponding
to all `A` values greater than `A[i]`.

For that, we sort the indices `i = index[.]` according to the values `A[i]`.
For a given `i = index[j]`, all canditate indices correspond to the `index[k]`, for `k > i`.

A simple loop allow to find the minimum and maximum values of these `index[k]`.

The complexity is dominated by the sorting: O(nlogn)

Here is a code in C++, rather simple and easy to understand whatever the language you are using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

int max_vol (const std::vector<int> &A) {
    int vmax = 0;
    int n = A.size();
    std::vector<int> index(n);
    std::iota (index.begin(), index.end(), 0);
    auto comp = [&] (int i, int j) {return A[i] < A[j];};
    std::sort (index.begin(), index.end(), comp);
    int index_max = index[n-1];
    int index_min = index[n-1];
    for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; --i) {
        int d0 = std::abs (index[i] - index_max);
        int d1 = std::abs (index[i] - index_min);
        int vol = std::max (d0, d1) * A[index[i]];
        if (vol > vmax) vmax = vol;
        index_max = std::max(index[i], index_max);
        index_min = std::min(index[i], index_min);      
    }
    return vmax;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> heights = {2, 9, 6, 3, 5, 7};
    auto max_volume = max_vol (heights);
    std::cout << "max volume = " << max_volume << std::endl;
}
```