# Trapping Rain Water(algorithm)

Tags: algorithm

That is a question at leetcode website.
https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/

Given n non-negative integers representing an elevation map where the width of each bar is 1, compute how much water it can trap after raining.

I wrote the solution below.

```
int solution(vector<int>& height) {
    int total = 0;
    for (auto pos = height.begin(); pos != height.end(); pos++) {

        if (*pos <= *(pos + 1))
            continue;
        for (auto lmaxpos = pos; *pos >= *(pos + 1); pos++) {
            total = total + *lmaxpos - *(pos + 1);

            for (; *(pos + 1) <= *lmaxpos; pos++) {
                total = total + *lmaxpos - *(pos + 1);
                if (*pos >= *(pos + 1)) {
                    total = total - (lmaxpos - pos) * (*lmaxpos - *pos);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

But after testing, i find that i have made some logical mistakes and i cann't find it out.
kindly ask you for help.

Comment: Note that the page that you link is not in English. Better to copy the problem in the post as text.

Comment: LC will tell you which examples your algorithm fails on. If it's a smaller input that you can solve by hand, you should first draw out and verify the answer. Next, you'd examine your solution; if there seems to be a calculation error, then fix it; if there's an issue with your algorithm, you'll have to go back to the drawing board. If that's too much work you can always look at the top voted answer for reference.

Comment: Seems the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65834270/10553341

Comment: Here is the Leetcode page, in English: https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/

Comment: yes,i know that there are better ways to slove with it.but i just want to know what's wrong with my idea.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the array from both directions, storing the max_height seen so far. Now for each index, the water at that index is max(0, min(left_max, right_max) - cur_height).

E.g.,

```
input:          [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1]
max_from_left:  [0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
max_from_right: [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1]
water:          [0-0, 1-0, 2-2, 2-1, 2-0, 2-1, 3-3, 2-2, 2-1, 2-2, 1-1]
water:          [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
sum(water) = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a commented/explained solution.

Find maximum height of bar from the left end upto an index i in the array \text{left_max}left_max.
Find maximum height of bar from the right end upto an index i in the array \text{right_max}right_max.
Iterate over the \text{height}height array and update ans

```
from typing import List


def trapping_water_container(list: List) -> int:
    l = 0
    r = len(list) - 1

    total, maxL, maxR = 0, 0, 0


    while l < r:
        # Identify the pointer with the lesser value
        if list[l] <= list[r]:
            # Check if the value for the left
            # pointer is smaller than MaxLeft
            if list[l] < maxL:
                # Calculate the volume for this pointer
                total += maxL - list[l]
            else:
                # Update the MaxLeft
                maxL = list[l]
            l += 1
        else:
            # Check if the value for the right
            # pointer is smaller than MaxRight
            if list[r] < maxR:
                # Calculate the volume for this pointer
                total += maxR - list[r]
            else:
                # Update the MaxRight
                maxR = list[r]
            r -= 1
    return total
```