# Giving run time error on submit but correct output on custom test case on a leetcode problem

Tags: c, logic

Problem link:-
https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/

Below is my solution to the question above. It passed the test cases, but on submit gives a runtime error. I used the test case(that resulted in runtime error) as custom input and it gave me the correct answer but is giving an error for same input on submit.

```
#define MIN(a, b) ((a<b)?a:b)

int cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return(*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

int maxArea(int* height, int heightSize)
{
    int size = 100; 
    int arr[size], k = 0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<heightSize-1;++i)
        for(int j=i+1;j<heightSize;++j)
        {
            arr[k++] = (abs(i-j)* MIN(height[i], height[j]));
            if(k==size)
            {
                qsort(arr, k, sizeof(int), cmp);
                arr[0] = arr[k-1];
                k = 1;
            }
        }
        
    qsort(arr, k, sizeof(int), cmp);
    
    if(k==0)
        return arr[0];
    int max = arr[k-1];
    return max;
}
```

test case - [1,8,6,2,5,4,8,3,7]

Comment: I guess it is not your first issue, but note that your code is really inefficient. In particular, you could avoid all the sorting. Just keep trace of the maximum area value. Other efficiency improvements are possible.

Comment: Complexity O(n log n). If I am not wrong, this is the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834270/calculate-largest-tanker-volume-in-one-dimensional-array/65835393#65835393